# Proportional/Percentage values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have this data frame:

```
o   d   r   kz  p
1   3   1   5   NaN
1   3   2   0   NaN
1   10  1   7   NaN
1   10  3   1   NaN
1   10  2   2   NaN
```

I would like to fill up the 'p' column by the proportions of 'kz' values for each pair of 'o' and 'd'. The result should look like:

```
o   d   r   kz  p
1   3   1   5   100%
1   3   2   0   0%
1   10  1   7   70%
1   10  3   1   10%
1   10  2   2   20%
```

I am thinking of looping through the data frame and assign a list of lists of `kz` values and then regressively fill up the `p` column.

Is there any elegant way to do it e.g. with `groupby` or `Pivot` table?

Comment: Can you explain first rows calculations?

Comment: There are certainly elegant ways, provided you tell us how `p` is supposed to be computed. Here it could be `kz / d` or `kz / (o * d)` and probably many other expressions. Which one is the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in several steps:

- Compute the sum per group with `groupby` [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `agg` [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html).
- Merge these values with you current dataframe with `merge` [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).
- Compute the ratio

Here the code:

```
# Import modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1,   3,  1,   5,   np.NaN],
     [1,  3,  2,   0,   np.NaN],
     [1,  10,  1,   7,   np.NaN],
     [1,  10,  3,  1,   np.NaN],
     [1,  10,  2,   2,   np.NaN]],
    columns=["o", "d", "r", "kz", "p"])
print(df)
#    o   d  r  kz   p
# 0  1   3  1   5 NaN
# 1  1   3  2   0 NaN
# 2  1  10  1   7 NaN
# 3  1  10  3   1 NaN
# 4  1  10  2   2 NaN

# Compute the sum per group
sum_ = df.groupby(['o', 'd']).agg({'kz': 'sum'})
sum_.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(sum_)
#    o   d  kz
# 0  1   3   5
# 1  1  10  10

# Merge these values with the current dataframe
df = df.merge(sum_, on=['o', 'd'], how="outer", suffixes=('', '_sum'))
print(df)
#    o   d  r  kz   p  kz_sum
# 0  1   3  1   5 NaN       5
# 1  1   3  2   0 NaN       5
# 2  1  10  1   7 NaN      10
# 3  1  10  3   1 NaN      10
# 4  1  10  2   2 NaN      10

# Compute teh ratio
df.p = df.kz / df.kz_sum * 100
print(df)
#    o   d  r  kz      p  kz_sum
# 0  1   3  1   5  100.0       5
# 1  1   3  2   0    0.0       5
# 2  1  10  1   7   70.0      10
# 3  1  10  3   1   10.0      10
# 4  1  10  2   2   20.0      10
```

Answer (score 1):

First *sum()* 'kz' column group by 'o' and 'd' and store it in the 'tmp'. Merge those two data frames. Then calculate the percentage value 'p' using the original value of 'kz' and sum value of 'kz'. Drop sum value of 'kz' and rename the original column name to 'kz'.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'o' : pd.Series([1,1,1,1,1]),
      'd' : pd.Series([3,3,10,10,10]),
      'r' : pd.Series([1,2,1,3,2]),
      'kz' : pd.Series([5,0,7,1,2]),
      'p' : pd.Series(None)}

# creates Dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

tmp=df.groupby(['o','d'])["kz"].sum()
merge_tmp=pd.merge(df, tmp, on=['o','d'], how='inner',suffixes=('_org','_tmp'))
merge_tmp['p'] = ((merge_tmp['kz_org']/merge_tmp['kz_tmp'])*100)

merge_tmp = merge_tmp.drop('kz_tmp', axis='columns')
merge_tmp = merge_tmp.rename({'kz_org': 'kz'}, axis='columns')
print(merge_tmp)
```